# tastypie obj_delete method does not work

Tags: python, django, web-services, rest, tastypie

I have the following code in tastypie. "obj_delete"  method does not work (will not be invoked) for 'ContextResource' class. what is problem?

```
class ContextResource(ModelResource):
    created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'created_by', full=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Context.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'context'
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(), SessionAuthentication())
        always_return_data = True
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

        filtering = {
            "name": ALL,
            "id": ALL,
            "query": ALL
        }

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        print '&& create context'
        bundle.data['created_by'] = bundle.request.user
        bundle = super(ContextResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
        self.create_xml(bundle)
        return bundle

    def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle = super(ContextResource, self).obj_update(bundle, **kwargs)
        self.create_xml(bundle)
        return bundle

    def obj_delete(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        print 'delete context'
        bundle = super(ContextResource, self).obj_delete(bundle, **kwargs)
        context_generator = ContextGenerator()
        context_generator.delete(name=bundle.obj.name)
        return bundle
```

Comment: may I see your code about sending "delete" request for client side code? I think your delete request from client will not be delivered by the api resource.